# How well does a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370 graphics card work?

Tags: hardware, graphics, ati

I`m going to buy new laptop with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370 graphic card, and i want to ask could be any problems using ubuntu on my laptop with this card?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Ubuntu Forums, everything should work. While [this guy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1679341) does have some questions about the configuration, he's saying that it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope that everything will be fine, just don`t want back to windows...

Comment: @Pheon You're welcome. Hope it works out for you.